# How to prove in three ways that $A_n$ is a normal subgroup of $S_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

I know how to prove in one way that $A_n$ is a subgroup of $S_n$ but I do not know how to prove that $A_n$ is a normal subgroup of $S_n$ in three different way

Comment: Which way do you know?

Comment: A subgroup of index $2$ is always normal. How different do you expect the three proofs?

Comment: The one that axotatxe mentioned, also $\;A_n=\ker\phi\;,\;\;\phi:S_n\to\{-1,\,1\}\;$, and $\;A_n^\sigma=A_n\;$ for any $\;\sigma\in S_n\;$ .

Comment: Well, a subgroup is normal iff it is invariant under every inner automorphism. This should give you another way to prove $A_n\trianglelefteq S_n$.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an outline of the methods I would use:

1. Argue using the fact that $[S_n: A_n]=2$. (You can either use the cosets directly, or else argue that the normalizer of $A_n$ has to be strictly larger than $A_n$.)
2. Argue using the fact that the parity of transpositions of $h$ and $ghg^{-1}$ are the same.
3. Show that $A_n$ is the kernel of a group homomorphism of $S_n\to \{-1, 1\}$.